# Update View in Angular 4.x After Updating Content

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I have an Angular Application in Which I have a `UserComponent` with Crud functionality. Everything working good but I don't know how to update the view when I Update a particular record. For a delete operation, I simply filter the array of objects to Update the view. But I want to Know how to update view after an update operation.

I have tried to calling the function like this:-

```
Observable.timer(5000).first().subscribe(()=>this.functionName());
```

But I don't want to call that function in every 5s.Only call when update statement is executed.

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialogRef, MD_DIALOG_DATA } from "@angular/material";
import { User } from "app/user";
import { FormGroup ,Validators,FormControl} from "@angular/forms";
import {UserService} from "../user.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-user',
  templateUrl: './update-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-user.component.css']
})
export class UpdateUserComponent implements OnInit {
  UpdateForm : FormGroup;
  User : User;

  constructor(@Inject(MD_DIALOG_DATA) private data: { user: User }, private mdDialogRef: MdDialogRef<UpdateUserComponent>,private userService : UserService) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.User=this.data.user;
    this.UpdateForm=new FormGroup({
      Id : new FormControl(this.User.Id),
      FirstName : new FormControl(this.User.FirstName,[<any>Validators.required]),
      LastName : new FormControl(this.User.LastName,[<any>Validators.required]),
      Email : new FormControl(this.User.Email,[<any>Validators.required]),
      Mobile : new FormControl(this.User.Mobile,[<any>Validators.required]),
    })
  }

  Save(model : User)
  {
      this.userService.Update(model).subscribe(res=>{
             this.mdDialogRef.close(); 
      });
  }

}
```

Service to update the database

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Headers} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(private _http : Http) { }
   Update(model : any)
  {
    var headers= new Headers();
     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     return this._http.put("/api/Update/",JSON.stringify(model),{headers : headers}).map(res=>res.json());
  }
}
```

Comment: Where/how do you update the particular record?

Comment: Wouldn't you react to the changes to the data, something like `ngAfterContentChecked` would give you an event on every change.

Comment: No I don't Know how to use `ngAfterContentChecked` can you please give an example

Comment: @echonax I am updating the database

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh can you share the code?

Comment: Why don't you call your function inside the subscribe block in `this.userService.Update(model).subscribe(` ?

Comment: the real problem is that I am showing Update in MdDialog (another component) and I want to reflect it into `UserComponent`

Comment: So you have something like `dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe( result =>...` on your UserComponent?

Comment: because, I believe your data is sent back inside the `this.mdDialogRef.close( {data:"all-of-it-here"} );`

Comment: Ok Thanks Dylan I'll try That :)